# Make several underbrace more compact (to look nice)

Tags: math-mode, macros

Is there a way to make underbrace symbols thinner and reduce their (vertical) distance in order to achieve this:

[image]

I've tried one tikz-version of thinner braces. While zooming in one can see, that those are a workaround and don't look very nice.

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\def\Underbrace#1{%
  \@ifnextchar_{\tikz@@underbrace{#1}}{\tikz@@underbrace{#1}_{}}}
\def\tikz@@underbrace#1_#2{%
  \tikz[baseline=(a.base)] {\node[inner sep=2] (a) {\(#1\)};
  \draw[line cap=round,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt}]
    (a.south east) -- node[pos=0.5,below,inner sep=7pt] {\(\scriptstyle #2\)} (a.south west);}}

\begin{document}

\[ p(x) \cdot x - \underbrace{r \cdot \Underbrace{\eta}_{\equiv 1} \cdot x}_{\text{variable costs}} \]

\end{document}
```

The result so far is:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Why not put the outer one as an overbrace or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the package `MnSymbol`, which allows for smaller braces. In addition you could use `\smash` so that the smaller brace is closer to the eta symbol. Finally, you could use the package `mathtools` and `\clap` to avoid too much space after the minus sign.

Here you have the code/pictures showing the 3 successive improvements I described:

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}       
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
p(x)\cdot x-\underbrace{r\cdot\underbrace{\eta}_{\equiv1}
\cdot x}_{\text{variable costs}}\\[5pt]
%
p(x)\cdot x-\underbrace{r\cdot\underbrace{\smash{\eta}}_{\equiv1}
\cdot x}_{\text{variable costs}}\\[5pt]
%
p(x)\cdot x-\underbrace{r\cdot\underbrace{\smash{\eta}}_{\equiv1}
\cdot x}_{\clap{\scriptsize variable costs}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even use a second smash to lift the larger brace:

```
p(x)\cdot x-\underbrace{\smash{r\cdot\underbrace{\smash{\eta}}_{\equiv1}
\cdot x}\vspace{6mm}}_{\clap{\scriptsize variable costs}}
```

where you can play with the "6mm" value.

[image]

Comment: This looks very good! I didn't know the \smash command yet. Thank you :)

Comment: Be aware though that you might have some issues if you use `MnSymbol` with other (more or less standard) packages as e.g. `amssymb`. Anyway, maybe the `smash` + `clap` trick is enough to get what you wanted.

Comment: I got these issues indeed. Can't use this code in my document :/ but it really looks nice.

Answer (score 9):

Building on other answers, I've imported the stuff from `MnSymbol` to define both `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`.

Then I've used them together with `\mathclap`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%------------------ MnSymbol stuff ------------------%

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsX}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\downbrace}    {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'251}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\downbraceg}   {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'252}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\downbracegg}  {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'253}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\downbraceggg} {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'254}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\downbracegggg}{\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'255}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbrace}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'256}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbraceg}     {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'257}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbracegg}    {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'260}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbraceggg}   {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'261}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbracegggg}  {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'262}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'263}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'264}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'265}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'266}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracemd}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'267}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracemu}      {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'270}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracemid}     {\mathord}{largesymbolsX}{'271}

\makeatletter
\def\horiz@expandable#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#8}%
  \@tempdima=\wd\z@
  \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#1}%
  \ifdim\noexpand\wd\z@>\@tempdima
    $\m@th#7#1$%
  \else
    \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#2}%
    \ifdim\noexpand\wd\z@>\@tempdima
      $\m@th#7#2$%
    \else
      \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#3}%
      \ifdim\noexpand\wd\z@>\@tempdima
        $\m@th#7#3$%
      \else
        \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#4}%
        \ifdim\noexpand\wd\z@>\@tempdima
          $\m@th#7#4$%
        \else
          \@mathmeasure\z@#7{#5}%
          \ifdim\noexpand\wd\z@>\@tempdima
            $\m@th#7#5$%
          \else
           #6#7%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}

\def\overbrace@expandable#1#2#3{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  #1#2{#3}\crcr\noalign{\kern2\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr}}}
\def\underbrace@expandable#1#2#3{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
  \noalign{\kern2\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  #1#2{#3}\crcr}}}

\def\overbrace@#1#2#3{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  #1#2\crcr\noalign{\kern2\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr}}}
\def\underbrace@#1#2#3{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
  \noalign{\kern2\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  #1#2\crcr}}}

\def\bracefill@#1#2#3#4#5{$\m@th#5#1\leaders\hbox{$#4$}\hfill#2\leaders\hbox{$#4$}\hfill#3$}

\def\downbracefill@{\bracefill@\braceld\bracemd\bracerd\bracemid}
\def\upbracefill@{\bracefill@\bracelu\bracemu\braceru\bracemid}

\def\upbrace@expandable{%
  \horiz@expandable
    \upbrace
    \upbraceg
    \upbracegg
    \upbraceggg
    \upbracegggg
    \upbracefill@}
\def\downbrace@expandable{%
  \horiz@expandable
    \downbrace
    \downbraceg
    \downbracegg
    \downbraceggg
    \downbracegggg
    \downbracefill@}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\overbrace}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette{\overbrace@expandable\downbrace@expandable}{#1}}\limits}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\underbrace}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette{\underbrace@expandable\upbrace@expandable}{#1}}\limits}
\makeatother

%------------------ MnSymbol stuff ------------------%


\begin{document}

\[ p(x) \cdot x - \overbrace{r \cdot \underbrace{\smash{\eta}}_{\equiv 1} \cdot x}^{\mathclap{\text{\tiny variable costs}}} \]

\end{document}
```